# How can i make this carousel working with JS and CSS?

Tags: javascript, carousel

I found this code on code pen : https://codepen.io/johnblazek/pen/nceyw.

I can't make it work on my project so I tried to use it with a test.php file linked to a style.css (as simple as that) and I still can't make it work.
I am new in coding and I can't figure out what is wrong.

I don't know if it is because I am using php or something else (by the way I can't use another language than php).

test.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JohnBlazek/codepen-resources/master/3d-carousel/css/stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <script type="text/javascript">https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JohnBlazek/codepen-resources/master/3d-carousel/js/libs.min.js</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js</script>

  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <h1>3D Carousel Using TweenMax.js & jQuery</h1>
    <h3>A pen by <a href="https://www.twitter.com/johnblazek" target="_blank">@johnblazek</a></h3>
    <div id="fps">Framerate: 0/60 FPS</div>
  </header>

  <div id="contentContainer" class="trans3d">
    <section id="carouselContainer" class="trans3d">
      <figure id="item1" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">1</div></figure>
      <figure id="item2" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">2</div></figure>
      <figure id="item3" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">3</div></figure>
      <figure id="item4" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">4</div></figure>
      <figure id="item5" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">5</div></figure>
      <figure id="item6" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">6</div></figure>
      <figure id="item7" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">7</div></figure>
      <figure id="item8" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">8</div></figure>
      <figure id="item9" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">9</div></figure>
      <figure id="item10" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">10</div></figure>
      <figure id="item11" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">11</div></figure>
      <figure id="item12" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">12</div></figure>
    </section>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {

    var slidersContainer = document.querySelector('.sliders-container');

    // Initializing the numbers slider
    var msNumbers = new MomentumSlider({
      el: slidersContainer,
      cssClass: 'ms--numbers',
      range: [1, 4],
      rangeContent: function (i) {
        return '0' + i;
      },
      style: {
        transform: [{scale: [0.4, 1]}],
        opacity: [0, 1]
      },
      interactive: false
    });

    // Initializing the titles slider
    var titles = [
      'King of the Ring Fight',
      'Sound of Streets',
      'Urban Fashion',
      'Windy Sunset'
    ];
    var msTitles = new MomentumSlider({
      el: slidersContainer,
      cssClass: 'ms--titles',
      range: [0, 3],
      rangeContent: function (i) {
        return '<h3>'+ titles[i] +'</h3>';
      },
      vertical: true,
      reverse: true,
      style: {
        opacity: [0, 1]
      },
      interactive: false
    });

    // Initializing the links slider
    var msLinks = new MomentumSlider({
      el: slidersContainer,
      cssClass: 'ms--links',
      range: [0, 3],
      rangeContent: function () {
        return '<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>';
      },
      vertical: true,
      interactive: false
    });

    // Get pagination items
    var pagination = document.querySelector('.pagination');
    var paginationItems = [].slice.call(pagination.children);

    // Initializing the images slider
    var msImages = new MomentumSlider({
      // Element to append the slider
      el: slidersContainer,
      // CSS class to reference the slider
      cssClass: 'ms--images',
      // Generate the 4 slides required
      range: [0, 3],
      rangeContent: function () {
        return '<div class="ms-slide__image-container"><div class="ms-slide__image"></div></div>';
      },
      // Syncronize the other sliders
      sync: [msNumbers, msTitles, msLinks],
      // Styles to interpolate as we move the slider
      style: {
        '.ms-slide__image': {
          transform: [{scale: [1.5, 1]}]
        }
      },
      // Update pagination if slider change
      change: function(newIndex, oldIndex) {
        if (typeof oldIndex !== 'undefined') {
          paginationItems[oldIndex].classList.remove('pagination__item--active');
        }
        paginationItems[newIndex].classList.add('pagination__item--active');
      }
    });

    // Select corresponding slider item when a pagination button is clicked
    pagination.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (e.target.matches('.pagination__button')) {
        var index = paginationItems.indexOf(e.target.parentNode);
        msImages.select(index);
      }
    });

  })();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css :

```
html, body{ background-color:#1a948d; }

body
{
  background-image: url('background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  width:100%;
  background-size:cover;
  height:100%;
  min-height:1000px;
  overflow:hidden;
  font-family: 'quicksandlight', Helvetica, Arial;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
  filter: dropshadow(color=#000000, offx=1, offy=1);
}

header
{

  margin-top:30px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:5;
  width:420px;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;

}

h1{

  font-size:36px;
  letter-spacing:-2.5px;
  margin-left:30px;
}

h3{

  font-size:16px;
  letter-spacing:-1.5px;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-left:35px;
}

#fps
{
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-left:35px;
}

a
{
  color:rgba( 255, 255, 255, .65 );
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover
{
  color:rgba( 255, 255, 255, 1 );
}

/* hardware accelatator class */
.trans3d
{
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

  /*-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
  backface-visibility:hidden;*/
}

#contentContainer
{
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:-500px;
  margin-top:-500px;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  width:1000px;
  height:1000px;
}

#carouselContainer
{
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:-500px;
  margin-top:-500px;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  width:1000px;
  height:1000px;
}

.carouselItem
{
  width:320px;
  height:130px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-left:-160px;
  margin-top:-90px;
  visibility:hidden;
}

.carouselItemInner
{
  width:320px;
  height:130px;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  border:10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  color:aqua;
  font-size:72px;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-left:-160px;
  margin-top:-90px;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:50px;

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? And what do you think is broken?

Comment: Someone else responded with the solution but thanks for the concern man

Answer (score 1):

Your imported scripts and JavaScript code are not quite right. Try this:

```css
html, body{ background-color:#1a948d; }

body
{
  background-image: url('background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  width:100%;
  background-size:cover;
  height:100%;
  min-height:1000px;
  overflow:hidden;
  font-family: 'quicksandlight', Helvetica, Arial;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
  filter: dropshadow(color=#000000, offx=1, offy=1);
}

header
{

  margin-top:30px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:5;
  width:420px;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;

}

h1{

  font-size:36px;
  letter-spacing:-2.5px;
  margin-left:30px;
}

h3{

  font-size:16px;
  letter-spacing:-1.5px;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-left:35px;
}

#fps
{
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-left:35px;
}

a
{
  color:rgba( 255, 255, 255, .65 );
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover
{
  color:rgba( 255, 255, 255, 1 );
}

/* hardware accelatator class */
.trans3d
{
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

  /*-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
  backface-visibility:hidden;*/
}

#contentContainer
{
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:-500px;
  margin-top:-500px;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  width:1000px;
  height:1000px;
}

#carouselContainer
{
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:-500px;
  margin-top:-500px;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  width:1000px;
  height:1000px;
}

.carouselItem
{
  width:320px;
  height:130px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-left:-160px;
  margin-top:-90px;
  visibility:hidden;
}

.carouselItemInner
{
  width:320px;
  height:130px;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  border:10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  color:aqua;
  font-size:72px;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-left:-160px;
  margin-top:-90px;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:50px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JohnBlazek/codepen-resources/master/3d-carousel/css/stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JohnBlazek/codepen-resources/master/3d-carousel/js/libs.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
  <script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <h1>3D Carousel Using TweenMax.js & jQuery</h1>
    <h3>A pen by <a href="https://www.twitter.com/johnblazek" target="_blank">@johnblazek</a></h3>
    <div id="fps">Framerate: 0/60 FPS</div>
  </header>

  <div id="contentContainer" class="trans3d">
    <section id="carouselContainer" class="trans3d">
      <figure id="item1" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">1</div></figure>
      <figure id="item2" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">2</div></figure>
      <figure id="item3" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">3</div></figure>
      <figure id="item4" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">4</div></figure>
      <figure id="item5" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">5</div></figure>
      <figure id="item6" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">6</div></figure>
      <figure id="item7" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">7</div></figure>
      <figure id="item8" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">8</div></figure>
      <figure id="item9" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">9</div></figure>
      <figure id="item10" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">10</div></figure>
      <figure id="item11" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">11</div></figure>
      <figure id="item12" class="carouselItem trans3d"><div class="carouselItemInner trans3d">12</div></figure>
    </section>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  // set and cache variables
        var w, container, carousel, item, radius, itemLength, rY, ticker, fps; 
        var mouseX = 0;
        var mouseY = 0;
        var mouseZ = 0;
        var addX = 0;
        
        
        // fps counter created by: https://gist.github.com/sharkbrainguy/1156092,
        // no need to create my own :)
        var fps_counter = {
            
            tick: function () 
            {
                // this has to clone the array every tick so that
                // separate instances won't share state 
                this.times = this.times.concat(+new Date());
                var seconds, times = this.times;
        
                if (times.length > this.span + 1) 
                {
                    times.shift(); // ditch the oldest time
                    seconds = (times[times.length - 1] - times[0]) / 1000;
                    return Math.round(this.span / seconds);
                } 
                else return null;
            },
 
            times: [],
            span: 20
        };
        var counter = Object.create(fps_counter);
        
        
        
        $(document).ready( init )
        
        function init()
        {
            w = $(window);
            container = $( '#contentContainer' );
            carousel = $( '#carouselContainer' );
            item = $( '.carouselItem' );
            itemLength = $( '.carouselItem' ).length;
            fps = $('#fps');
            rY = 360 / itemLength;
            radius = Math.round( (250) / Math.tan( Math.PI / itemLength ) );
            
            // set container 3d props
            TweenMax.set(container, {perspective:600})
            TweenMax.set(carousel, {z:-(radius)})
            
            // create carousel item props
            
            for ( var i = 0; i < itemLength; i++ )
            {
                var $item = item.eq(i);
                var $block = $item.find('.carouselItemInner');
                
        //thanks @chrisgannon!        
        TweenMax.set($item, {rotationY:rY * i, z:radius, transformOrigin:"50% 50% " + -radius + "px"});
                
                animateIn( $item, $block )                      
            }
            
            // set mouse x and y props and looper ticker
            window.addEventListener( "mousemove", onMouseMove, false );
            ticker = setInterval( looper, 1000/60 );            
        }
        
        function animateIn( $item, $block )
        {
            var $nrX = 360 * getRandomInt(2);
            var $nrY = 360 * getRandomInt(2);
                
            var $nx = -(2000) + getRandomInt( 4000 )
            var $ny = -(2000) + getRandomInt( 4000 )
            var $nz = -4000 +  getRandomInt( 4000 )
                
            var $s = 1.5 + (getRandomInt( 10 ) * .1)
            var $d = 1 - (getRandomInt( 8 ) * .1)
            
            TweenMax.set( $item, { autoAlpha:1, delay:$d } )    
            TweenMax.set( $block, { z:$nz, rotationY:$nrY, rotationX:$nrX, x:$nx, y:$ny, autoAlpha:0} )
            TweenMax.to( $block, $s, { delay:$d, rotationY:0, rotationX:0, z:0,  ease:Expo.easeInOut} )
            TweenMax.to( $block, $s-.5, { delay:$d, x:0, y:0, autoAlpha:1, ease:Expo.easeInOut} )
        }
        
        function onMouseMove(event)
        {
            mouseX = -(-(window.innerWidth * .5) + event.pageX) * .0025;
            mouseY = -(-(window.innerHeight * .5) + event.pageY ) * .01;
            mouseZ = -(radius) - (Math.abs(-(window.innerHeight * .5) + event.pageY ) - 200);
        }
        
        // loops and sets the carousel 3d properties
        function looper()
        {
            addX += mouseX
            TweenMax.to( carousel, 1, { rotationY:addX, rotationX:mouseY, ease:Quint.easeOut } )
            TweenMax.set( carousel, {z:mouseZ } )
            fps.text( 'Framerate: ' + counter.tick() + '/60 FPS' )  
        }
        
        function getRandomInt( $n )
        {
            return Math.floor((Math.random()*$n)+1);    
        }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Enijar, it worked ! I feel a bit stupid right now but thanks for the help man !